# Mysql On trigger each row

Tags: mysql

i need help for the below code. My problem is that i want only that code executes once per statement (after i search i checked that expression don't exists anymore only once per row). 
So i tried to add:

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
    (Select count(*) FROM replay_replays_access WHERE id_game = new.id_game GROUP BY id_game HAVING count(*) <5) 
THEN
```

But didn't work either what can i do, its duplicating sometime triplicating the information?

```
TRIGGER replay
AFTER UPDATE
ON table_replays FOR EACH ROW
begin
    IF EXISTS 
        (SELECT 
            replay_games.room_name 
        FROM replay_games 
        WHERE replay_games.room_name = 'Tournament Room' and replay_games.id = new.id_game) 
    THEN
      IF NOT EXISTS 
        (Select 
             count(*) 
         FROM replay_replays_access 
         WHERE id_game = new.id_game 
         GROUP BY id_game 
         HAVING count(*) <5) 
       THEN
         INSERT INTO replay_replays_access(id_game, id_player, replay_name, do_not_hide)
             SELECT 
                 new.id_game, 
                 replay_users.id , 
                 CONCAT(
                   (SELECT game_types 
                    FROM replay_games 
                    WHERE id=new.id_game),
                   ': ',
                   (SELECT 
                       descr 
                    FROM replay_games 
                    WHERE id=new.id_game)) , 
                 0 
             FROM replay_users 
             WHERE 
                 (replay_users.admin > 0 OR 
                     replay_users.privlevel = 'TOURNAMENT MEMBER') 
                 AND NOT replay_users.name = (
                     SELECT 
                          replay_games.creator_name 
                     FROM replay_games 
                     WHERE replay_games.id = new.id_game);
      END IF;
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: FOR EACH STATEMENT should be FOR EACH ROW - is that a typo?

Comment: 'i want only that code executes once per statement' - not with you, the trigger will execute for every row updated in table_updates.  Can you add sample data the update statement you are using and expected outcome please.(all as text)

Comment: Sorry my bad i corrected with was once per row

Comment: Did you just change to "for each row" because it is required, but still want something that works for the whole statement? MySQL fundamentally does not support this. If your query is supposed to be a workaround for that, you should explain what it is supposed to do, but keep in mind that the trigger will still fire for every row. You may also describe your requirements/problem, so we may be able to suggest a different solution, but you would need to add table defs, your query, example data, current and expected result (e.g. the "triplicating information" that you want to get rid of).